# BaseRequestOptions angular2 error after import

Tags: http, angular

I'm working with angular2 project, but im new in angular2. I have a problem  after i do

```
import { BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
providers: [
...
..,BaseRequestOptions 
]
```

Error is that:

> Object { __zone_symbol__error: Error, fileName: Getter, lineNumber:
>   Getter, columnNumber: Getter, message: Getter, name: Getter, stack:
>   Getter, originalStack: Getter, zoneAwareStack: Getter, toString:
>   createMethodProperty/props[key].value(), 3 more… }

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is still in **Experimental Phase** of Angular.

You need to use the **BaseRequestOptions** and create your custom options, so that you can inject them into request options under your providers list

Use as below,
Import the below

```
import {HTTP_BINDINGS, Http, BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';
```

Construct your custom Options class exteding the BaseRequestOptions

```
class MyCustomOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
  search: string = 'testingTeam=true';
}
```

Injecting it is tricky, you will have to bind them during your application bootstrap as

```
bootstrap(App, [HTTP_BINDINGS, bind(RequestOptions).toClass(MyCustomOptions)])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Here, you bind it to the default RequestOptions, so that you say your angular to use **to include your custom options and they are valid**..

More Details on this API **[document](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/BaseRequestOptions-class.html)**.